# Point Release upgrade: Unable to update Ubuntu 14.04.1 to 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

Very trivial question, but current version of Ubuntu installed on desktop is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS as verified by

```
sanchit@sanchit-Home:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

then,

```
sanchit@sanchit-Home:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
sanchit@sanchit-Home:~$
```

Why is it not upgrading?

Comment: Did you do "sudo apt-get update" ?

Comment: Yes,  I did that before "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade"